# JavaScript get max value min value average of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

i want the user to enter a few marks and at the end i want to display the highest lowest average how many got a make of "A","B","C","D","F"

```
var highestMark=0;
var gradeAwarded;
var StudentArr= [Student];
var markArr = [mark];
var Student = prompt("Enter Student Name: ", "Name");
var mark = prompt("Enter Student Mark: ", 50);
var max = Math.max.apply(markArr); /* This about equal to Math.max(numbers[0], ...) or Math.max(5, 6, ..) */
var min = Math.min.apply(markArr);

if (mark < 0 || mark > 100) {
    alert("Grate out of bounds");
} else if (mark >= 83) {
    gradeAwarded = "A";
} else if (mark >= 70) {
    gradeAwarded = "B";
} else if (mark >= 50) {
    gradeAwarded = "C";
} else if (mark >= 0) {
    gradeAwarded = "F";
}
document.write(min);
```

Comment: For future reference, Java != JavaScript

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Gqn6r/

Comment: What's your question? What don't you like about your code?

Comment: You are using the variable names `Student` and `StudentArr`, you should change them to `student` and `studentArr`. In JavaScript it is a [convention](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) to only use names that start with a capital letter for [constructor functions](http://helephant.com/2008/09/14/constructor-functions/). If someone else who is familiar with JS looks at your code and sees variables that start with capital letters it might confuse them because they may assume that those variables are constructors, not whatever they really are.

Comment: Also, it looks like you've posted what amounts to the same question a couple of times before. On Stack Overflow [you shouldn't do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions). If you instead edit your question, adding more detail, clarifying the question more or just adding info about what you have tried to do to solve the problem since you posted the question, the edit will bump your question back up to the front page so more people will see it and possibly give you an answer you like more.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) allows you to [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) over an array.

```
var min = markArr.reduce(
    function (a,b) { return Math.min(a, b); },
    Infinity);
var max = markArr.reduce(
    function (a,b) { return Math.max(a, b); },
    -Infinity);
var mean = markArr.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0)
         / markArr.length;
```

---

You've got a number of issues with your code though.

```
var markArr = [mark];
var Student = prompt("Enter Student Name: ", "Name");
var mark = prompt("Enter Student Mark: ", 50);
```

You're using `mark` to initialize `markArr` before reading `mark`.

Also, `mark` is read as a string.

You should reorder your statements so that you initialize variables before using them, and you
should make sure `mark` ends up as a numeric value.

```
var mark = +prompt("Enter Student Mark: ", 50);
```

The `+` before prompt coerces the string returned by `prompt` to a number.

Comment: Note that while functionally elegant, calculating the min/max/mean by iterating over the array three times is not ideal. Further, `Math.max.apply( ary )` is far more elegant and efficient than `ary.reduce( Math.max, -Infinity )`

Comment: @Phrogz, I agree re efficiency but I disagree re "ideal"; this is a class exercise so clarity is important and the efficiency won't be noticable in an interactive program even if `marks.length` is the size of the largest undergraduate class in the world.  If you wanted to be really efficient you keep running totals as you received the data to make the most out of the idle time while you're waiting for user input instead of doing anything in batch, and you'd avoid function call overhead.

Comment: The first two don't work - passing Math.min or Math.max to Array.prototype.reduce returns NaN.

Comment: @BenCollier, reduce passes 4 arguments, and min is varargs.

Answer (score 0):

You can just sort the array and take the first and last value. For example:

```
arr = [3, 5, 2, 14];
arr.sort(function(x, y){return x-y});
min = arr[0]; // 2
max = arr[arr.length - 1]; // 14
```

Note that a custom comparison function is necessary since you want numerical sorting instead of lexical sorting of the string representation of the numbers. (Otherwise, "14" would be 'smaller' than "2", which is obviously not the way you want it.)

For the record, I agree with Mike Samuel on the other issues with your code.

Comment: Sorting to find the min/max is interesting, but not very efficient. Now, if the median were wanted as well…